# Differentiable function $f$ such that $[f(x)]=0 \iff x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x$ be a real number. Is there a differentiable function $f$ such that $[f(x)]=0 \iff x=0$, where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$?

Comment: @  Babak S: No, the question is still in the website.

Comment: I do not remember its topic. Maybe I find a solution for it. If you can then I am raedy to ask it again.

Comment: How I can construct a $\mathbb Z$-basis for a free group?

Comment: Yes, it was removed by one of the modedator of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of $[\cdot]$: if it always truncates towards zero, no. Because $f(0)$ lies in the open set $(-1,1)$ so for $x$'s close to zero we will have $[f(x)]=0$ as well (due to the continuity of $f$).

If you mean truncating down, then the answer is yes, and some examples were given in Marvis' answer.

Answer (score 3):

For example, consider $$f(x) = -x^{2n}$$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: @ Marvis: Thank you very much for the quick and efficace answer.